# Android retrofit2 image file upload to Spring Boot REST end point

Tags: android, spring-boot, image, rest, retrofit2

I am attempting to upload an image file through Android retrofit2 to a Spring Boot REST end point.

The code (in java) in controller class for the end point is as follows:

```
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @PostMapping("/user/testupload")
    public void testUploadImage(@RequestParam("productImage")MultipartFile file) throws IOException{

        productImageService.uploadImage(file);
    }
```

When I test the API end point from postman it works fine.  Here is the code snippet generated by postman for Java-okHTTP:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("productImage","/C:/eclipseprojects/images/image.jpeg",
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
    new File("/C:/eclipseprojects/images/image.jpeg")))
  .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://localhost:9966/user/testupload")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("Authorization", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtLm5hemlyQHZvbHVudGVlci5oZWFydGZ1bG5lc3Mub3JnIiwiaWF0IjoxNjkzOTIyMzMwLCJleHAiOjE2OTM5MjMyMzB9.YtH4DQ_MYyMsVpKkGrKdEXhURFHFnNzqH3wjSR53PBVKDupgj6iXU4KyPOMaVe7BoSZHSqYvy65EPq8RIe3IGg")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

But, I find it difficult to write code in Android Studio (Kotlin) to upload an image to this end point.  Here is what I have in Android Studio:

API Service:

```
interface SavePhotoAPI {
    @Multipart
    @POST("user/testUploadImage")
    suspend fun uploadUImage(
        @Part image: MultipartBody.Part
    ) : BaseResponseModel
}
```

Retrofit builder:

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(
        authInterceptor: AuthInterceptor
         ):Retrofit{
         val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
         interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
         val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
             .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
             .addInterceptor(interceptor)
             .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
             .build()

         return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .build()
    }
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSavePhotoAPI(retrofit: Retrofit): SavePhotoAPI {
        return retrofit.create(SavePhotoAPI::class.java)
    }
```

Finally here is how I call the service from my viewmodel:

```
suspend fun uploadImage(myFile: File){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        var temp = BaseResponseModel()
        try {
            temp = savePhotoAPI.uploadUImage(
                MultipartBody.Part
                    .createFormData("productImage", myFile.name, myFile.asRequestBody())
            )
        }
        catch(e: IOException){
            temp.message = "IO Errpr"
        }
        catch(e: HttpException){
            temp.message = "Http error"
        }
        Log.i("MYTAG7","temp ....$$temp")
    ~~~
When I run my app, I get 404 Error - that it could not find the end point.  What am I doing wrong?  Please help.

Thanks
```